# DocuSign Unexpected error: invalid_grant on production server

Tags: php, docusignapi

I have implemented DocuSign php sdk on a development server and I tested for a couple of weeks and everything works as expected.
Now that I wanted to move the developed code to a production server I am getting Unexpected error: invalid_grant when trying to get a token.  The code still works fine in the dev server and no change has been made to the code, so I cannot figure out why is not working in a different server.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour with DocuSign tech support, it turned out that my server was 2 minutes fast.  After adjusting the time, everything started to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the [Go-Live process](http://multiple%20environments) and get your app approved for use with DocuSign production Severs.

If you already done so, than you must ensure everything is configured the same in production. The configuration is not going to be automatically copied over for you. Ensure you have the secret or RSA key etc. Think of auth as "starting from scratch" in production, only you have written the code, all other configurations are different (except your Integration Key which is copied over).

Comment: thank you for your answer.  Yes, my app was already approved in the go-live process.  Can you clarify what do mean by "The configuration is not going to be automatically copied over for you" and "all other configurations are different".  What kind of things are a problem to docusign api?

Comment: are you using JWT or Auth Code Grant?

Comment: JWT based on eg-01-php-jwt from the GitHub repo

Comment: did you create an RSA private key in production? or are you using the one from before? did you update the impersonated user GUID for the production one?

Comment: No, I am using everything exactly the same from the dev server.  The impersonated user is also the same since I am authenticating against the same user.  Should I create a new set of keys and GUID for every server I want to deploy to?

Comment: everything is different. Sorry, I know it's not clear. The user is different, even if they have the same email and name. They have a different GUID in the DocuSign servers (which are different, different env, URL)

Comment: as for your question  "Should I create a new set of keys and GUID for every server I want to deploy to? " do you mean your own server? then no. But you just changed environments on the DocuSign side, from the developer/demo/sandbox to production. That is a one time change that does require you to create and update these things.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I'll try renewing credentials in my new server and report back.  Thanks.